# Can't get the data that stored in Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to create a user after he verified the code that I send him
so first I generate the code in `sendCode` resolver and save it in Redis using `setex`

the problem is that code is set in Redis but when I try to use it in `createUser` resolver using `get` it returns null.

```
const sendCode: MutationResolvers["sendCode"] = async ({
  input: { phoneNumber, email },
}: {
  input: SendCodeInput;
}) => {
  const code = generate4digitNum();
  await redis.setex(phoneNumber ?? email, THREE_MINS, code);
      return {};
    };



const createUser: MutationResolvers["createUser"] = async ({
  input: { ...userData },
}: {
  input: CreateUserInput;
}) => {
  
  const code = await redis.get(userData.phoneNumber ?? userData.email);
  if (code !== userData.code) {
    throw new Error(errors[0].id);
  }


  user = await userModel.create({ ...userData});

  return {type: user.type, _id: user._id };
};
```

the redis.ts file that I create:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  port: Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
});

client
  .on("connect", function () {
    console.log(`connected ${client.connected}`);
  })
  .on("error", function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

export const get: (key: string) => Promise<string> = promisify(client.get).bind(
  client
);

export const setex: (
  key: string,
  seconds: number,
  value: string
) => Promise<string> = promisify(client.setex).bind(client);
```

I will appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you are using the same key it is set too? you have email or phone number in both places. Could you be setting it to email and trying to retrieve it with phoneNumber?

Comment: @about14sheep that was my first thought but I also add the exact key string that was saved in redis instead of email and phoneNumber but I still get null

Comment: what does redis return when you set it?

Comment: When I ckeck the key in redis-cli it gives me the code that I saved but in node it return null

Comment: might be how you are using `promisify`. have you tried just exporting the redis client and using `redis.client.setex`? [Promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) assumes that original is a function taking a callback as its final argument in all cases

Comment: @about14sheep when use get in the scope of `sendCode` it gives the same code that I set but it gives me null in `createUser` scope

Comment: What version of Node Redis are you using? Node Redis 4.x no longer requires the usages of promisify. Maybe the problem is buried in there?